# The symbols after “(“ in buttons behave differently in c sharp in wpf [zh-cn]

Tags: c#, wpf

The symbols after `(` in buttons behave differently.

I have 2 buttons in a dialog box namely, <kbd>Save</kbd> and <kbd>Cancel</kbd>.

I also have a name and value pair in a resource file, where the value for different languages are given.

In my problem, I have the ZH-CN (traditional Chinese) in my resource file.

If I give the data in my resource file as

> SAVE       保存 (_S)
>
> CANCEL 取消 (_C)

My output become

[image]

The closing bracket becomes reversed and comes to the beginning.

I tried increasing the size of the buttons as well, the output remains the same.

Code:

```
<Button Content="{x:Static resx:Resources.ShareCancel}"                                           
Name="CancelBtn" 
DataContext="{Binding}" 
Command="{Binding CancelCommand}"/>
        
<Button Content="{x:Static resx:Resources.ShareSave}"
Name="ShareBtn"
Command="{Binding ShareCommand, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has to do with the flow direction property, which probably gets inherited from one of parent controls.
People had encountered similliar problem and it seems like this is a bug:

- [Round brackets not showing up correctly in RightToLeft flow direction in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835920/round-brackets-not-showing-up-correctly-in-righttoleft-flow-direction-in-wpf))
- [Weird rendering behavior in WPF for ToolTips with brackets or parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389649/weird-rendering-behavior-in-wpf-for-tooltips-with-brackets-or-parentheses)

The simplest solution is to set the FlowDirection in buttons

```
<Button Content="{x:Static resx:Resources.ShareCancel}"                                           
Name="CancelBtn" 
DataContext="{Binding}" 
Command="{Binding CancelCommand}"
FlowDirection="LeftToRight"/>

<Button Content="{x:Static resx:Resources.ShareSave}"
Name="ShareBtn"
Command="{Binding ShareCommand, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
FlowDirection="LeftToRight"/>
```